# How to do hierarchical document searching in Java?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

How to search document's in hierarchical structure in Google Doc api?

I have hierarchical folder structure in google doc like below..

```
-TestFolder  
---Test1  
-------Foo  
-------BAR  
---Test2   
-------Foo  
-------BAR
```

My search query is like so:

https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder/TestFolder/Test2?title=Foo&title-exact=true&showfolders=true

Still I was get back folder resource id of Foo from test1, actually need to search exact search in nested structure.

How to search in hierarchical structure for folder's in Google Doc?

How to do nested folder search of document and folder in Google Doc using Google Doc list api?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of this myself, there is no mechanism provide by google doc any which directly we can put some url with hierarchy and get folder list and doclist, for this i have to do create some new method with use google do api, which will traverse whole path with resource id and then finally we will get nested folder resource id and its contents.